# how do you save chunks into new csv files and automatically name the csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I'm a bit stuck on how to save the chunks into there own separate csv file.
Here is what I'm trying to do :

1. 1-1000 rows >bracelet_no_variants_1000.csv
2. 1001-2000 rows >bracelet_no_variants_2000.csv
3. 2001-3000 rows >bracelet_no_variants_3000.csv

```
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv("bracelet_no_variants.csv")

def split(df, chunk_size):
    indices = index_marks(df.shape[0], chunk_size)
    return np.split(df, indices)

chunks = split(df, 1000)

for c in chunks:
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv("bracelet_no_variants.csv")
l=[i*1000 for i in range(len(df)//1000+1)]+[len(df)]
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    temp=df.iloc[l[i]:l[i+1]]
    temp.to_csv('bracelet_no_variants_'+str(l[i+1])+'.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use chunksize from read_csv function, and iterate pur chunks to save them to csv as

```
 pd.read_csv("bracelet_no_variants.csv",chunksize=1000)
 counter=1000
 for chunk in chunks:
        chunk.to_csv("bracelet_no_variants_"+str(counter)+".csv")
        counter=counter+1000
```

you might need to pass `index=False`to to_csv function to stop saving index as column.

if you dont want header in all csv files, set header True for first iteration only

```
 pd.read_csv("bracelet_no_variants.csv",chunksize=1000)
 counter=1000
 header=True
 for chunk in chunks:
         chunk.to_csv("bracelet_no_variants_"+str(counter)+".csv",header=header)
        counter=counter+1000
         header=False
```

Comment: I might need to edit my question for this but is there a way to make sure it keeps  things together  for example from column a : product, sku, sku, rule, rule ,product, sku, sku, sku, rule, rule, rule and the split always happens after the last rule .@A.B

Comment: you can create nee question for this to get better reach ss its slightly different question

Comment: Also, try to share first fee rows desired snd current output when uou post new question